# how to get unique filename in erlang yaws

Tags: erlang, yaws

I am creating application that upload media files(audio,video and images) using erlang in yaws web server.There multiple user can upload files concurrently so how can i get unique filename every time ?

Please suggest me solution.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you have two ways to do that :

- 1 : You store a base ID in a database (like "a") which will be the name for the next file uploaded, and you increment the ID each time you add a file ("b", "c", "aa", "aA", ...). For exemple, this is the the kind of techniques used by youtube or url-shortner.
- 2 : You hash the file (with MD5, SHA1, CRC32, ...) and the resulting hash will be the name of the file on your server. Since hash should be unique for each file, you shouldn't have name collision.

The hash technique is usually more CPU-intensive (because you will need to hash every file uploaded), but you can then provide the hash to your clients to check the integrity of the file.

If you want to keep the original name of the file, you will need a database (like mnesia if you are using erlang) to store each relation (ID -> orignal name, or Hash -> original name).

Comment: _Since hash should be unique for each file, you shouldn't have name collision._ It is nonsense. Each hash has collisions because a hash has typically fewer bits than data. The difference between different hashes is a probability of collision. CRC32 is out of a debate. Making collisions in CRC32 is a task for kindergarten with an IT programme. MD5 is not a good choice either. There is known way to generate collisions within seconds. For SHA1, there is not known a practical solution but is principally weak in the same way as MD5 is. Go for SHA2 hash family of SHA3 which is much better.

Comment: I know, but why would you want to generate collision in this case ? I guess, depending on how you implement the upload, you could overwrite files, but it would be very bad not to check if the hash is already present in your database.

Comment: Your users will generate collisions by accident. See [Birthday paradox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) for more details. Your users can have bad intentions as well. If you will check your hash in a database you will ruin one of biggest benefits of hashing. Scalability! Guess what is using Dropbox and why.

Comment: Ho, I didn't know that. So the birthday paradox means that the probability of having two file with the same hash doesn't grow linearly compared to the number of file you actually have stored ? I'm sorry, I didn't really understood the last part of your comment.

Comment: The birthday paradox says that if you have SHA1 which has 2^160 unique hashes and you will store for example 2^40 files (trillion files) you have approximately 1/(2^120) chance to make collision by accident. It is pretty good. It doesn't tell you how easy is to make collision intentionally and it is a reason why you should use MD5. CRC32 is out of the debate because it is broken by the fact you start with 2^32.

Comment: The second part is about the thing, that hash computation is perfectly independent of hash computation of different data. It allows you to get part of hash and use it for distributing work, storage, everything. You can store one file to multiple places and gain robustness. You can do it asynchronously. If you add a database, you ruin it. The storing by hash is a form of a database itself. All that you need is to compute a hash, store by the hash and return the hash. Let client associate hash with the original name.